# Probability to draw cards

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The problem:

> Given a pack of cards of 10 different kinds, the probability to draw a card of type $1$ is $\frac{1}{3}$. The probability to draw a card of type $i$, for every $i=2,...,10$ is $\frac{2}{27}$. We can assume that the cards types are independent. What is the probability that the $15$th card being drawn is of a type we haven't drawn yet?

I'm kind of lost here. Since the probability to draw card of type $1$ and $2,...,10$ is different, I don't know how to treat this data.

Help will be much appreciated!

Comment: are you drawing with or without replacement?

Comment: Each card being drawn gets back to the pack

Comment: It would have to be with replacement since the size of the deck was not mentioned. But it sounds strange to say that the card types are independent. How could they not be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We compute the probability $P(i)$ that the $15$th card is the first of type $i$.

In the case $i = 1$, we get (the first $14$ cards must be of type $\neq 1$, the $15$th card must be of type $1$)
$$P(1) = (1 - 1/3)^{14} \cdot (1/3) = \frac{16384}{14348907}.$$

In the case $i \neq 1$, we get
$$P(i) = (1 - 2/27)^{14} \cdot (2/27) = \frac{74505805969238281250}{2954312706550833698643}.$$

So the answer to the question is
$$P(1) + P(2) + \ldots + P(10) = \frac{16384}{14348907} + 9\cdot \frac{74505805969238281250}{2954312706550833698643} = \frac{74880619336820362274}{328256967394537077627} \approx 22.8\%.
$$

Comment: I am willing to bet 100 of any currency in the world you didn't do the calcuations by hand :D

Comment: @Lost1: Of course, for the fractions there was a friendly computer helping me. :)